# Folder size linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, directory

I need to monitor folders on my linux machine periodically to check whether they are exceeding certain limits.

I have checked stat function call but running stat recursively on all sub folders and files is time consuming and I need to do this for all folders.

Does kernal maintain any datastructures which I can interpret in my program.Or is their any standard api for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to enforce limits then use [quotas](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Quota.html)

Answer (score 3):

In case the quota mechanism isn't suitible, then 
[inotify](http://inotify.aiken.cz/) might be handy:

From wikipedia:

> inotify is a Linux kernel subsystem
>   that acts to extend filesystems to
>   notice changes to the filesystem, and
>   report those changes to applications.report those changes to applications.

Comment: I have checked inotify events, folder size monitoring is not present in this

Comment: @siri Yes, I know, but you can hook to every IN_CLOSE_WRITE and perform some actions instead of doing it all the time without knowing if anything changed in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Type

```
du -sm directory_name
```

Will give you the total size of the directory in megabytes recursively.

Type

```
man du
```

for help with this command.

Answer (score 1):

You want quotactl:

```
quotactl -- manipulate filesystem quotas

SYNOPSIS
     #include <sys/types.h>   /* types needed by quota.h */
     #include <sys/quota.h>   /* for disk quotas */
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling stat recursively is the only way to get the current folder size.  If you want to continuously monitor the file system, take a look at inotify.

Comment: Although, be careful which stat fields you use to figure out the amount of space used.  You probably need to round the usage for each file or directory **up** to the next multiple of `st_blksize`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Axel. However if you really need to do this in code, you could execute the **du** shell command via popen:

```
FILE* pf = popen("du -ch [your folder] | grep total")
```

Then read the output from the command via the file handle and fgets(...)

Answer (score 0):

Use command du, check this link ...
["How To Check Folder Size"](http://www.cocodede.com/2011/08/como-saber-el-tamano-de-un-folder-en-linux/)